# GeoServer layers data not showing on hosted WebGIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I made a webgis and it has feature adding layer from GeoServer. It works fine on localhost but when I hosted the website its only hosting the HTML and cannot get/show the data from the GeoServer. Is there any way to fix this?

This is in localhost and how its should be
[image]

This on my hosted webgis
[image]

Comment: can the hosted machine see your geoserver machine?

Comment: @IanTurton no, it only shows my WebGIS front end

Comment: What address are you using?

Comment: @IanTurton you mean the url for getting the geoserver data? If it is the url are still using localhost

Comment: On a hosted server you should use a real address not local host

Comment: @IanTurton how to get the real address?

Comment: how are you hosting the server? this is basic web hosting not GIS

Comment: @IanTurton i use github to hosting the server

Comment: can you give me a complete tutorial or something to hosting a webgis using geoserver leaflet and postgis?